Is the relativistic energy-momentum relation fundamental?
The following relativistic energy-momentum relationship is taken to be fundamental:
$$E^2=p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4.\tag{1}$$
Let us specialize to massless particles ($m_0=0$) so that we have:
$$E=p\ c.\tag{2}$$
But is Eqn.$(2)$ fundamental?
Consider photons travelling in a medium with refractive index $n(k)$ so that the dispersion relationship is given by:
$$\omega(k)=\frac{c}{n(k)}k.\tag{3}$$
Quantum mechanics gives the following relationships:
$$E = \hbar\ \omega,\tag{4}$$
$$\mathbf{\vec{p}}=\hbar\ \mathbf{k}.$$
Therefore for photons travelling in the medium the energy-momentum relationship Eqn.$(2)$ becomes
$$E = p\ \frac{c}{n}.\tag{5}$$
Is Eqn.$(2)$ simply a specialization of the more general Eqn.$(5)$?

Does this answer your question? Are special relativity calcs affected by media?

Thanks, is the effective mass of the polariton in the dielectric given by $m=E/(c/n)^2$ where $E$ is photon energy and $n$ is the refractive index?
